# Running a php piece of code on backend indefinitely and without any request from front frontend

Tags: php, api, backend, server-side

I'm kinda new to backend programming.
I want to check an api for weather of couple of cities from another website every 6hour and save the data that I receive in a database. This should be done without any request from front end.
Any idea how can I do that?

Comment: use cron for this type of tasks.

Comment: Look into cron jobs. You can set a schedule on the server, and it will run the requested script for you.

Comment: Lots of people told you about cron jobs and that's an important topic to understand - but you specifically asked how to run code indefinitely.  To answer your question, the set_time_limit() function lets you adjust (or remove) the maximum execution time.  This can also be configured in your php.ini file.  See: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.set-time-limit.php

Additionally, see https://www.php.net/manual/en/info.configuration.php#ini.max-execution-time

You should know that PHP's default settings disable the maximum execution time when invoked from the command-line, including cron.

Answer (score 1):

use your server cron job
It lets you set a path to a php script and let you choose at what time you want it to run.